# process.MainWindowHandle always returns zero in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm trying to get title of web sites opening in chrome browser. The same code works fine in console application but in windows service "process.MainWindowHandle" always returns zero.

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Process[] processCollection = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process process in processCollection)
    {
        string processName = process.ProcessName;
        if ((processName.ToLower() == "chrome") && process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            string logContent = process.MainWindowTitle;
            WriteToFile(logContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Windows services don't have access to interactive desktops, such as the one used by any logged in users who might be running chrome. You're approaching this problem from the wrong direction if you're trying to track website usage via window titles.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this?   @Damien_The_Unbeliever